# difference between [] and \(\) in Basic Regular Expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Consider:

```
$ echo '<H1>heading</H1>' | grep '<H\(1\|3\|2\)>.*</H\1>'
$ <H1>heading</H1>
```

and

```
$ echo '<H1>heading</H3>' | grep '<H[1-3]>.*</H\1>'
$ grep: Invalid back reference
```

first command works just fine.

1. Doesn't `[1-3]` and  `\(1\|3\|2\)` both mean 1 or 2 or 3 ? if not why? and what the difference between them?
2. why back-reference works with only `\(\)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `()` means «groupping» which means set a part of the *string* which can operate as 1 item, and for backrefference too.
- `[]` means *symbols* set

So if you use parenthesis just for single symbols the meaning is same. But usually it used for multisymbol strings like `(cat|dog)`

Answer (score 8):

Re part 1: Yes, both patterns will match a 1 or a 2 or a 3.

Part of the answer to your first question *is* your second question.  Funnily enough.

Parentheses are used to enable backreferences, and to clarify operator priority/grouping.

Square brackets enclose a *character class*.  They are used to match *one* instance of the character set inside.

For example, `\(hello\)` would match the word "hello" and would also put it in the appropriate backreference variable (`\1`, `\2`, etc.)

On the other hand, `[hello]` would match a SINGLE character, one of the set {e,h,l,o}.

Some additional data (just extra info):

Backreferences are based on the sequence of the open paren, not the close paren.  With nested parens this can become important.  Ignoring escape characters for readability—`(this (that) (the other))` will result in `\1` containing `this that the other`; `\2` containing `that` and `\3` containing `the other`.

A count on a character class checks for more instances of that character class.  They don't have to match in the same way.  For instance, `[0-9]` will match a single digit, and `[0-9]{5}` will match any five digits.  If you want to only match 5 *repeated* digits, e.g. match 77777 or 33333 but not 37497, use a backreference: `\([0-9]\)\1{4}`

Comment: Note that I've never quite gotten the hang of which special characters need to be backslashed to work in `grep`—I think `{}` may actually need backslashes to work properly and define a count.

Comment: The shell that you're using can affect usage of backslashes as well.

Comment: The two equivalent expressions would be '\(1\|3\|2\)' and '\([1-3]\)'. The brackets replace the OR expression, not the parentheses.

Comment: well who would know better about wildcards other than wildcard?

Comment: your last sentence is not working: `echo 1111 | grep  -E '([0-9])\1{4}'` does not work

Comment: @edwardtorvalds, if you're trying to match only *4* repeated digits, change the `{4}` to a `{3}`.  There is one digit matched by the character class in parentheses, *plus* the digits matched by the backreference and count (with the count specified within curly braces).  The line I specified is to match *5* repeated digits and does work for that.

Comment: You could also use `echo 11111 | grep -E '([0-9])\1\1\1\1'` instead; does that make it clearer?

Comment: ok I found my mistake