# sed syntax to remove certain elements

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to use "sed" to remove "\n", "\r", "Connected." and " " from a string.

```
echo "   Connected. 
97  " | sed -e 's/[Connected.|\n|\r\ ]//g'
```

The result I expect to get back is "97".

Comment: Take out the square braces.  What did you think they are for?  They don't belong there at all.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236637/135943, actually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between \[\] and \‌(\‌) in Basic Regular Expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236637/difference-between-and-in-basic-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` cannot be removed that way by classic (POSIX) `sed`, they are line delimiters and are not part of the string that is subject to the `s///` substitution.
They should be removed by `tr` afterwards:

```
sed -e 's/Connected\.//g' | tr -d ' \r\n'
```

(since we use `tr`, we make it remove every single char of interest)

However, you may use a single `s///` instruction with GNU `sed` which can operate on a whole file at once with the `-z` option (which is not a very good idea on large files):

```
sed -z -r -e 's/Connected\.|\n|\r| //g'
```

Comment: When the `\n` is deleted away, then the behavior of `sed` will be unpredictable as it expects `\n` line endings in Unix world.

Comment: Of course also POSIX `sed` can remove newlines. Just join all lines in a loop and then for the last line operate on it as you did with GNU option `-z`.

Comment: You are both right. @Philippos You may want to propose a better alternative by appending it to my answer.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Answer edited.